# Why Main() not main() in C#?

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

In C, C++, JAVA we use `main()`, but in C# `Main()`

Why main() method is changed to Main() in C#?
Is there any strong reason behind this?

Eager to know this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) in C# recommend first letter of a method name to be capitalized (in fact, they recommend Pascal casing).

Answer (score 1):

Naming conventions are different in C#

Answer (score 1):

C# methods and properties tend to be capitalize while variables tend to have lower case first letters followed by bumpy case.